# how long would it take to be abducted?

Tags: time-series, probability

112 children in a population of 76,000,000 were abducted in one year. I've seen that statistically speaking, and based on these stats, if a child stood on the street every single day it would take 750,000 years for them to be abducted.

I can't figure out how this is calculated.

Comment: People say stuff all the time without a valid methodology. So unless you know where this came from I would wonder if its an academic analysis that used formal methods. No time series would ever predict that many years ahead, few predict beyond a few years in my experience. Since children are leaving and entering the system this would be difficult to calculate - and in this case nonsensical since none of the children would live that long.

Comment: @user54285 is right, but this is a word problem about the Poisson distribution (probably negative binomial, thinking a few more minutes), not a legitimate question about crime.

Comment: Simplify the numbers to get some intuition.  For instance, if apples drop from a tree at random intervals but on average ten drop per minute, how long on average would you expect to wait for each apple to drop?  Now do the same calculation with your numbers.

Comment: I am impressed you caught that Dave :) I was trying to imagine how one would do this as a time series. I guess you are suggesting this could be done with arrival rates (which come to think of it does use a Poisson distribution)?